# Is it possible to generate the oauth token for multiple scopes in api manager 3.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying api manager 3.1.0. In one of my API I have defined couple of scopes and added them to the resources.

Example,

Say I have defined two scopes called, add_emp, view_emp(both of them are linked to couple of roles) and added these two scopes for couple of resources like for the first resource /employees linked view_emp and for the second resource /create linked add_emp. And while generating the oauth token cant we generate the token for mulitple scopes, like for the given role he should be able to view employee as well as add employee. But, for the other role only he should be able to view the employee.

While trying this use case. I noticed that, it is not taking multiple scopes. Even though I am passing multiple scopes while generating the token like "scope=add_emp view_emp" the token is getting generated for only add_emp but not for both. But the same use case is working fine on api manager 3.0.0. Is this an issue? or am I doing something wrong.

Please suggest me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a token with multiple scopes, the user who is requesting the token must have all the roles that are associated with scopes.

Eg:

scope_1 : role_A

scope_2 : role_d, role_e

The user should have either, `role_A + role_d` or `role_A + role_e` in order to get a token with both scopes.

Otherwise, a token with only the scope bound to a particular role will be returned.

Therefore, re-check whether the user has roles that associate with both scopes.